# knife configuration to a chef server on google cloud

Tags: chef-infra, google-compute-engine

Currently, I have a chef server and workstation in the same project on GCE. I want to configure my knife file to point to the server. While I can point to the servers external IP address is there another way to do this?

Ideally, I would like to configure it to the chef servers internal IP address. This means that if the chef server gets switched off and placed with a new IP address knife will still know where it is. Is this possible?

Comment: Reverse proxy and use DNS names?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you cant point to private ip address on knife configure command but you define it on the knife.rb file.
Heres mine that worked.

```
current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "mynode"
chef_server_url          "https://{privateid}"
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
```